# How to hide/display survey pop up based on url bar?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, url

There are 2 applications. My application is written using Angular as front end `http://test.com/search`. My application contains javascript text which pop-ups survey whenever user visit our website.

There is another application `B say - http://test.com/search?dodhaLink=true` from where user can access my application too.

**What I am trying to achieve is when my application is called from application B then dont show pop-up window.**

**Qualtrics javascript text in .html file**

```
<div>
<!--BEGIN QUALTRICS WEBSITE FEEDBACK SNIPPET-->
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function(){var g=function(e,h,f,g){
this.get=function(a){for(var a=a+"=",c=document.cookie.split(";"),b=0,e=c.length;b<e;b++){for(var d=c[b];" "==d.charAt(0);)d=d.substring(1,d.length);if(0==d.indexOf(a))return d.substring(a.length,d.length)}return null};
this.set=function(a,c){var b="",b=new Date;b.setTime(b.getTime()+6048E5);b="; expires="+b.toGMTString();document.cookie=a+"="+c+b+"; path=/; "};c=a[1];if(100==c)return!0;switch(a[0]){case "v":return!1;case "r":return c=a[2]%Math.floor(100/c),a[2]++,this.set(f,a.join(":")),!c}return!0};
try{(new g(100,"r","QSI_S_ZN_cwOHfLkxRr4n4W2","https://zncwohflkxrr4n4w2-nlmenterprise.siteintercept.qualtrics.com/SIE/?Q_ZID=ZN_cwOHfLkxRr4n4W2")).start()}catch(i){}})();
</script><div id='ZN_cwOHfLkxRr4n4W2'><!--DO NOT REMOVE-CONTENTS PLACED HERE--></div>
<!--END WEBSITE FEEDBACK SNIPPET-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` in order to check the URL of the page from javascript.

so you can try:

```
if('http://test.com/search'.equals(window.location.href))
{
    // display survey
}
```

Comment: check the proper url using: `console.log(window.location.href)`